# Is the expression "etwas ist vom Laster gefallen" used almost always figuratively?

Tags: expression

> Weil es irgendwo unterwegs **vom Laster gefallen** sein soll.

They are looking for a certain object, and there is no mention of a lorry in previous contexts. Which leads me to think that the sentence does not have a literal meaning.

In English, the expression "something fell off the truck" means "something was stolen". I wonder if this is a German equivalent of this expression?

Comment: The part _irgendwo unterwegs_ makes me thinking, it is the literal meaning in this case. In the figuratively meaning, I would not expect such a detail.

Comment: @knut Hi. There has so far been no mention of someone being on their way to somewhere, either. I agree: the part "irgendwo unterwegs" seems a bit too descriptive for the entire sentence to be interpreted figuratively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, it *can* have a literal meaning. It apparently happens from time to time that things fall off trucks.

In most cases, however, the expression means the exact same thing as in English.